# Automate writing by sending commands to Vim

Tags: python, bash

I would like to write a script to automate at a constant speed the rewriting of an already existing file, say file.txt, in Vim, so if I do
`$ ./script file.txt`
it opens Vim and writes every character at a constant speed, then `ESC :x`. I want to do it because I want to record a split terminal writing two programs, say one in C, the other one in Python, at constant speed, to visually compare.

I've tried xdotool so something like
`$ vim file.txt && xdotool key i`
and I would put the right hand side in a for loop going through all the characters in file.txt, sadly it does not work, it writes the `i`, it does not press it to enter INSERT mode in Vim, then I also tried writing a Python script.

```
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.write("vi file.txt")

pyautogui.press("enter")
pyautogui.press("i")
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.write("test")

pyautogui.press("esc")

pyautogui.write(":x")

pyautogui.press("enter")
```

but that does not work too. It opens Vim and closes it suddenly after writing everything to the terminal.

Comment: Do you need to automate vim specifically, or would something that prints at a constant rate of characters per second also work? In any case, [vhs](https://github.com/charmbracelet/vhs) might be worth a look.

Comment: what do u mean by "writes every character"? with vim's `r` command?

Answer (score 1):

`vi` accepts STDIN, so

```
#!/bin/bash
{ 
echo a
sleep 1
echo h
sleep 1
echo o
sleep 1
echo p
sleep 1
echo p
sleep 1
echo a
sleep 1
echo '^['
sleep 1
echo  ':wq'
} | vi hoppa.txt
```

will work.

(note: enter `^[` as control-V escape)

Comment: Why is sleep needed?

Comment: For demonstration purposes.